# Expected Value with cyclic probabilities.

Tags: probability

The problem if from [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1265/problem/E):

> You has $n$ mirrors, numbered from $1$ to $n$. Every day, You asks
>   exactly one mirror "Am I beautiful?". The $i$-th mirror will tell you
>   that you are beautiful with probability $p_i/100$ for all $1\le i\le n$.
>
> You ask the mirrors one by one, starting from the 1-st mirror. Every
>   day, if you asks $i$-th mirror, there are two possibilities:
>
> - The $i$-th mirror tells you that you are beautiful. In this case, if $i=n$ you will stop and become happy, otherwise he will continue
>     asking the $i+1$-th mirror next day;
> - In the other case, you will feel upset. The next day, you will start asking from the 1-st mirror again.
>
> You need to calculate the expected number of days until you become
>   happy.
>
> This number should be found by modulo 998244353

My solution is:
$$E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X=i)\cdot i$$
where $P(X=i)$ means that you became happy on day $i$-th which is $P(X=1)=p_1$, $P(X=2)=(1-p_1)p_2$ and so on. After $p_n$ it will cycle again from $p_1$.

that is 
$$\begin{align}E[X]&=\underbrace{p_1}_{a_1}+2\underbrace{(1-p_1)p_2}_{a_2}+3\underbrace{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_3}_{a_3}+\ldots n\underbrace{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\ldots(1-p_{n-1})p_n}_{a_n}\\
&+(n+1)\underbrace{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\ldots (1-p_n)}_{\alpha}\underbrace{p_1}_{a_1}+(n+2)\alpha \underbrace{(1-p_1)p_2}_{a_2}+\ldots 2n\alpha a_n\\
&+(2n+1)\alpha^2a_1+\ldots \end{align}$$
so
$$\begin{align}E[X]&=\underbrace{a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\ldots+na_n}_{\mu}\\
&+n\alpha(\underbrace{a_1+a_2+\ldots a_n}_{\theta})+\alpha(\underbrace{a_1+2a_2\ldots}_{\mu})\\
&+2n\alpha^2\theta+\alpha^2\mu\\
&+\ldots\end{align}$$
so
$$E[X]=\frac{\mu}{1-\alpha}+\frac{n\alpha\theta}{(1-\alpha)^2}$$
There are two examples given
- $n=1$, $p_1=50/100=1/2$. Putting this in gives $E[X]=2$
- $n=3$, $p_1=10/100=1/10,p_2=20/100=1/5,p_3=50/100=1/2$. Putting this in gives $E[X]=131/32$ and $131\cdot 32^{-1}\equiv 904658949\pmod {998244353}$ which is different from the given answer $112$.
What is wrong with my work?

Comment: I don't understand where modulo 998244353 came from.

Comment: I didn't follow the whole thing, but your setup is wrong. If $n>1$ then $Pr(X=1)=0$ (since he must go through at least $n$ days to go through all $n$ mirrors). In fact, if $i<n$ then $Pr(X=i)=0$ and $Pr(X=n)=p_1 \times p_2 \times ... \times p_n$.

Comment: @BalancedTryteOperators, probably because this problem came from a programming contest. You can read more about the number 998244353 here: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/62541

Comment: @roundsquare $Pr(X=i)$ means he is happy on day i therefore all mirrors before day i told him that he is not beautiful with probability $(1-p_1)(1-p_2)...(1-p_k))$ where $k+1=(i-1\mod n)+1$ (+1 on both sides because of 1-based index)

Comment: @RE60K I think you are misinterpreting the problem. He starts with mirror 1 on day 1 and if mirror 1 says he is beautiful, he moves to mirror 2 on day 2, etc.... If he gets through all the mirrors calling him beautiful (which would take n days) then he is happy. But, if any one of them says he isn't, then he starts over, and would need at least another n days to be happy.